# how to make a textbox accept only date of birth format c#

Tags: c#

I got a text box that accepts everything but i want to accept only date because its Date of birth box i used this code for the letter and digit but don't know how to use something like this for date of birth box

```
private void SurmaneTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) != true && Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) != true && !char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))

    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Your only allowed to enter letters, Please enter only letters e.g Smith");
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBV7Q.png)

Comment: what you want is a [Masked Text Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: what you want is a [DateTimePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably need a Masked Text Box, I am not using that often but I think this would be the syntax:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    maskedTextBox1.Mask = "00/00/0000";
}
```

This would, when the form is loaded, set the mask of the TextBox that the user can only enter a date.
Hope I helped.

Comment: that mask would accept "55/42/6843", leaving you with the need of validation after user completed insert. I'd go with a DateTimePicker, which will do all date validation for me.

Comment: @GianPaolo Yeah that would work too, but you could also just write a simple validation code.